# theoretical question regarding differential equations and cyclicality/periodicity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have learnt that if the characteristic polynomial representing a homogenous second order differential equation ($y''+ay'+by=0$) only has complex roots, then the standard solution is of the type $y=e^{ax}(c_1 \cos bx+c_2\sin bx)$. Would it then be correct to state that $a^2-4b<0$ is a *necessary and sufficient* condition for *all* solutions to the equation $y''+ay'+by=0$ to be cyclical/periodic functions?

Comment: You would also need $a = 0$, since the exponential term makes it nonperiodic.

Comment: @eyeballfrog 
so a=0 and b>0 would do the trick?

Comment: Yes, that should work.